# Which graph algorithm to solve this?

Tags: graph-algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path, minimum-spanning-tree, bellman-ford

Given is a undirected, weighted Graph. Each Node is either a "city" or a "village"; nodes are connected via the edges (=roads).

I start at Node 1 and have to bring a message to all of the cities.
In each city that is reached by someone, an arbitrary amount of people can help to spread the message (so they can start driving to another Node).

I'm now looking for minimum distance that have to be travelled on roads so that all cities got the message. (When x people use a specific road it also counts x times the edge weight)

Solution: I thought, it would be helpful to get a Minumum spanning tree between all the cities first. But the problem is, that there are villages as well. (--> "Steiner tree problem").
So I guess it might be possible to solve it somehow with Dijkstra or Bellman-Ford; or a combination of shortest path and MST?

Do you guys have an idea? I don't need code, but just a basic idea how to approach this would be very helpful:) Thanks.

Comment: If the villages are not of any importance, you can just remove them; if there is an edge like `City1` ---> `Village1` ---> `City2`, just remove the village in between and make an edge `City1` ----> `City2` with the weight as the sum of the two edges in the former.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you really made my day. What confuses me, is that this easy solution would maybe also be a solution for any Steiner tree problem?!  But maybe because I don't need to know which villages are visited, but only the distances this works for my problem. So I now used Dijkstra from Node 1 to find the nearest city and saved the distance. Then I used your approach to create a MST between the cities. The final solution is then the distance to the first city + distances in the MST. And it works:)

Comment: I just [read](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/steiner-tree/) about the Steiner Tree problem and realized that my solution is indeed wrong; it will work only for very special cases. For example, in [this graph](http://pasteboard.co/rNvAJIDso.png), considering that `5` is a village and the rest are cities, how can we possibly remove the village and maintain an equivalent of the original structure of the graph ?! On a side note, why were you using Dijkstra? Why not to just calculate the MST ?

Comment: In your graph, my program would delete 5 and create the following new undirected edges: 1-2, 1-y, 1-3, 2-3, 2-y, 3-y with their new corresponding edge weights.

Comment: Because I don't need to know which villages I visited, this is not a Steiner tree problem. I only need to know the distance traveled. If Node 1 is a village, I first need to know the shortest distance from Node 1 to the nearest city. Because the villages will later get removed and this information would be lost. So in total: First dijkstra if necessary, then remove villages / create new edges, create MST. @Anmol